# DbSet Add from another context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have two different services, each one have different context

```
_dbset = _contexto.Set<RecoveryUser>();
_dbset = _contexto.Set<User>();
```

Problem is when I try to use `_dbset.Add(user)` into RecoveryUser context, because user is into another context.

So I get:

> Cannot Convert model.User to model.RecoveryUser

I think I can made another method in User context to receive parameters of recoveryUser to solve it. But there is not another way to do that? Regards

Comment: One context expects model `User` and the other one `RecoveryUser`. I think the error is self explanatory.

Comment: Yes I know what is error, but my question is, I can´t call another service to save data with their context? I mean something like  `_userService._dbset.Add(user));`

Comment: You can add data to another context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self explanatory error:

> Cannot Convert model.User to model.RecoveryUser

What it means? Even if the two entities (User and RecoveryUser) are similar, even with the same property names and types, they are not the same. You have to convert between them.

How to solve:

```
_dbsetRecovery = _contexto.Set<RecoveryUser>();

_dbSetRecovery.Add(new RecoveryUser {
    UserId = user.UserId,
    // ... and all other properties
});
```